# Angularjs: Split template div in two with include fails because new div nested in original

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I am attempting to split a div in my template into two divs (for styling), with `</div><div>` inside html pulled in via data-ng-include.

Template:

```
<div id="content" data-ng-include data-src="content()"></div>
```

Controller ("thisview" is a string variable derived from url):

```
$scope.content = function () {
  var thiscontent = 'includes/content/' + thisview + '.html';
  return thiscontent;
};
```

included [thisview].html file (truncated):

```
        [...]
    </ul>
</div><!--closes div-->
<div id="anotherdiv">
    <p>
        [...]
```

When I load the page, the `</div>` (as above) is getting moved to the end, effectively nesting #newdiv inside #content. Is this an $sce thing (or other 'code-cleaning/fixing') that I can turn off?

I'd like to inject raw html as I see fit into my template.

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: I don't know if I understand right, but what you are trying to do -- close the `div` inside the include -- just doesn't seen right, in any point of view... Why don't you just create two `div` inside the included template and style it whit css?

Comment: I could do that, but it seems unnecessary because this is the only page (of about ten) where I need the extra div in the template, and if the include just came through as is, the code should 'just work' (it would be proper html). I'm adding a new div by 'splitting' the original (by inserting `</div><div>`) -- a basic and trivial coding method). Why doesn't that "seem right"? What difference does it make?